# signalR websocket error when try to connect multiple user at same time

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I'm using signalR, angular client with .Net Core, both projects frontend and backend are deployed to azure.
When I open a small number of client it works fine. but when try a loading test with many useres at same time the websockets fail.
I'm asking if I need to configure some things to enable a large number of user at same time.

Comment: Can you show your code please

Comment: Are you seeing any Cors issues in the console?

Comment: How large are you talking? There are some limits in Azure App Service https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits
The general recommendation when you want a large amount of connections is to use the Azure SignalR Service.

Comment: There are no cors issues , cors is ok . but when open many connection at same time it fail